# Remotely crashing a PC by only visiting a website? Is this an at least 6 year old WebGL bug?

Tags: web, remote-code-execution

http://hunger.hu/webgl.html

**WARNING:** only visit this website, it you don't mind crashing your PC!

so how is this possible? the website dates back to 2014! It is 2020 and by only visiting a website causes it to crash?

backup links for the html page:

backup page#1: https://pastebin.com/cjti4FRt

backup page#2: https://pastebin.pl/view/728cb64d

backup page#3: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hNtRzf6svc/

So I just turned the: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript to protect/mitigate myself from similar sites.

Comment: This actually didn't crash my PC. It caused my WebGL container to crash, but that's about it.

Comment: It briefly hung up Chrome until it killed WebGL and then things returned to normal.  In short, browsers have gotten better.